# Inject one xml file in the other (merge two xml files) in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xml-parsing

i'm working on a project where i have to put the translations in XML.
Now the xml translations file is auto generated, but not for my part of the project.
I, and they, do have to share the generated XML.

So when i enter my piece of XML in their 'main' XML, it's overwritten when the file is regenerated.
The current solution is to keep a separate file with my translations, and copy-paste it every time into the 'main' XML file.

Is there a way to do this automaticly? 
I tried the xml `Include` option, but Visual Studio doesn't recognize or use it.

I thought about generating some kind of placeholder in the 'main' XML, and that Visual Studio would 'somehow' replace the placeholder with the XML in my separate file.

Any idea's?

Comment: You could try marking the non-replaceable elements with an attribute so they will not get overwritten at regeneration, if you have access to the generation part you will just tell it to ignore the elements marked with your attribute so it will jump over them.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ae35ca/merge-2-xml-files-into-single-xml-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: I think you should look into resource files. They support automatic localization.

Comment: @Abhijeetchindhe that's not what i want: merge two files with C#

Comment: @Michel Would you please come take a look at the answer and see if any are satisfactory, and if not leave some comments?

Comment: How does this generated xml file come to your hands: do you read it from database or other place at runtime of your program, or is it checked in into your source repository and you add it to your project in VS2010 as one of the source files?

Comment: How would you define the place where you want to include your piece of xml into their generated xml: is it in the very end just before closing of root element, or you have a specific XPath of where to include it, etc?

Comment: @Denis: it is a source file in VS2010, and it can be at any place

Comment: I have added an example including a file on disk and a resource file in an assembly, pls check and let me know if its not working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to include xml files with ENTITY sections described [here](http://xml.silmaril.ie/includes.html). If .Net XmlReader does not do it automatically you will need to implement an XmlResolver for yourself and set it into the XmlReaderSettings before reading your root file. Overriding ResolveUri should be enough.

For example lets assume your xmls look like this:

root.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ENTITY generatedXML SYSTEM "generated.xml">
  <!ENTITY generatedXML2 SYSTEM "pack://application:,,,/generated2.xml">
]>
<root>
  &generatedXML;
  &generatedXML2;
  <extraContent>
    <extraValue Name="xa" Value="1"/>
    <extraValue Name="xb" Value="1"/>
    <extraValue Name="xc" Value="1"/>
    <extraValue Name="xd" Value="1"/>
  </extraContent>
</root>
```

generated.xml and generated2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<generatedContent>
  <generatedValue Name="a" Value="1"/>
  <generatedValue Name="b" Value="2"/>
  <generatedValue Name="c" Value="3"/>
  <generatedValue Name="d" Value="4"/>
</generatedContent>
```

Where "generated.xml" is located next to your root xml, and "generated2.xml" is located somewhere else in one of application assemblies and marked with "BuildAction = Resource". Then we can write an XmlResolver like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlResolution
{
    class XmlResourceResolver : XmlResolver
    {
        private static readonly string FileScheme = "file";
        private static readonly string PackScheme = PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;
        private ICredentials credentials;

        public override ICredentials Credentials
        {
            set { this.credentials = value; }
        }

        public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
        {
            if (absoluteUri.Scheme == FileScheme)
            {
                return File.OpenRead(absoluteUri.LocalPath);
            }
            else if (absoluteUri.Scheme == PackScheme)
            {
                return System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(absoluteUri).Stream;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the end we can read our xmls like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
            XmlResolver = new XmlResourceResolver()
        };

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("root.xml", settings))
        {
            var element = XElement.Load(reader);

            var nameValuePairs = from content in element.Elements()
                                 from value in content.Elements()
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Name = value.Attribute("Name"),
                                     Value = int.Parse(value.Attribute("Value").Value)
                                 };

            foreach (var pair in nameValuePairs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Name + " " + pair.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the ENTITY sections described there? I don't see any CDATA sections and CDATA wouldn't really make sense anyway (whereas ENTITY would, assuming XmlReader respects it).

Comment: You are absolutely right, i meant the ENTITY sections. It was like 3 in the morning sorry:)

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following (I'm not sure how you're reading it in so I'm going to assume you can use an XmlDocument, if not you can probably convert the XmlDocument to w/e you need):

```
ArrayList xmlNodes;
XmlNode newNode;

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument toInclude = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load("myFile.xml");
toInclude.Load("toInclude.xml");

xmlNodes = new ArrayList();

foreach (XmlElement ele in xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("toReplace"))
{
    xmlNodes.Add(ele);
}

foreach (XmlElement ele in xmlNodes)
{
    ele.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(toInclude.DocumentElement, true), ele);
}
```

This will replace any  tags with the root node of the toInclude.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataSet object too.

```
    XmlTextReader readerOne = new XmlTextReader("C:\\generated.xml");
    XmlTextReader readerTwo = new XmlTextReader("C:\\your-file.xml");

    DataSet dsOne = new DataSet();
    dsOne.ReadXml(readerOne);

    DataSet dsTwo = new DataSet();
    dsTwo.ReadXml(readerTwo);

    dsOne.Merge(dsTwo);
    dsOne.WriteXml("C:\\CompleteResource.xml");
    Console.WriteLine("Merge completed");
```

Comment: Michel seems to have made it clear that that is not what he wants when he wrote "@Abhijeetchindhe that's not what i want: merge two files with C#" referring to "http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ae35ca/merge-2-xml-files-into-single-xml-using-C-Sharp/"

Comment: Hi @CrazyCasta, I didn't see your message. I posted another solution at the end of this article.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the OP I thought: wouldn't it be nice to be able to associate to any xml file in a Visual Studio project - an XSL file to transform this file. The result of this transform would appear as a sub-item under the original xml file like *.xaml.cs appears under *.xaml. And we would be able to assign any Build Action to this new xml file via Properties.

This is not possible now but another more generic preprocessing technique exists - [T4](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/).
Here is the description how to use it for inserting "our" xml fragment into "their" generated xml file.

1) Let's assume that "their" generated xml file is included into our project under the name aaa.xml.

For example **aaa.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<abc>
  <data a="1"/>
  <data a="2"/>
  <placeholderForTranslations/>
  <data>ccc</data>
</abc>
```

where placeholderForTranslations element needs to be substituted by "our" fragment.

2) Let's add to our project the aaa.xslt file which transforms aaa.xml by replacing placeholderForTranslations with "our" fragment.

**aaa.xslt**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="placeholderForTranslations">
    <translations>
      <trans orig="aaa" translated="AAA"/>
    </translations>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first xsl:template here says that by default as transform engine goes through nodes of the input file it just copies them as-is to the output. The second template says that in case a placeholderForTranslations element is encountered, the fragment of xml embedded right here into the template will be used to substitute the placeholderForTranslations element. In fact, it is possible to modify *.tt file (see below) so that this fragment is also read from a separate file, if you wish.

3) Let's add aaa1.tt - t4 code preprocessor file into our project.

**aaa1.tt**:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Xsl" #>
<#
    string origXmlPath = Host.ResolvePath("aaa.xml");
    string transformPath = Host.ResolvePath("aaa.xslt");

    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transform.Load(transformPath);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    transform.Transform(origXmlPath, null, stream);
    byte[] generated = stream.ToArray();
    string generatedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(generated);
#>
<#= generatedString #>
```

Between <# and #> you can see a piece of C# code which finds the full paths to aaa.xml and aaa.xslt, then applies aaa.xslt transform to aaa.xml file and puts the result into the generatedString variable. Then with help of <#= generatedString #> the content of generatedString is inserted into the output file.

If you do these steps, on the first save of aaa1.tt in Visual Studio the file aaa1.xml will be created as a sub-item of aaa1.tt. To this file via its Properties you can assign Build Action, for example "Embedded Resource". You can also force regeneration of aaa1.xml at any time by right-clicking aaa.tt and selecting "Run Custom Tool". It is also always regenerated when you build your solution.

I thought the advantage of this approach is that your merged file is generated at compile time - not at runtime of application. So the file can be visually inspected during development.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, assuming you have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="ApplicationMainWindow_Button_RunWizard" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Ordenar Café</value>
  </data>
  <data name="ApplicationMainWindow_OrderCancelled" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Orden Cancelada</value>
  </data>
  <data name="ApplicationMainWindow_OrderComplete_Formatted" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>El costo de la tasa de café es de {0}, gracias.</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

And you want to merge with the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <data name="ApplicationMainWindow_Title" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Café de casa</value>
  </data>
  <data name="BeanType_Breakfast" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Grand Aroma</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Then you can code something like that:

```
public class XmlManager
{
    private XDocument _document1;
    private XDocument _document2;
    private string _autogenerated;
    private string _manual;
    private string _target;
    public XmlManager()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _autogenerated = @"c:\AutogeneratedResource.xml";
        _manual = @"c:\ManualResource.xml";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(_autogenerated);
        _document1 = XDocument.Parse(doc.InnerXml);

        doc.Load(_manual);
        _document2 = XDocument.Parse(doc.InnerXml);

        _target = @"c:\Target.xml";
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        if (_document2.Root != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = _document2.Root.Elements("data");
            if (_document1.Root != null)
                _document1.Root.Add(elements);

            _document1.Save(new StreamWriter(_target));
        }
    }
}
```